# Chef IIS cookbook default resource

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Working with the IIS cookbook to set the shared configuration directory

**iisconfigsettings.rb**

```
...

default['iis']['conf_dir']   = "#{iis['home']}d:\\configuration"
...
```

This should change the configuration directory to d:\configuration.

After chef run I get FATAL:  ArgumentError:  You must supply a name when declaring a default resource.

I'm not sure where the name should be specified here.  According to the documentation on chef, which isn't too specific I believe I have the parameters appropriate here.
https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/iis

Anyone have experience in settings this?

Comment: what is `iisconfigsettings.rb`?  Is it a recipe, attribute file, something else??

Comment: It's a recipe in my WebServerBuild cookbook.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that your calling the `default` method in a recipe context.  That appears to be attempting to create a resource of type `default`, and it is angry that you didn't give said resource a name.  Frankly, I'm a bit baffled about exactly what's happening there, or where you got a resource with the type of `default`, but luckily, the solution is simple:

**iisconfigsettings.rb**

```
...
node.default['iis']['conf_dir'] = "#{iis['home']}d:\\configuration"
...
```

Notice that I added `node.` in front of `default`.

Also, I'm not sure what you're after with `"#{iis['home']}d:\\configuration"`.  That's not just going to give you `d:\configuration`, it's going to pre-pend whatever `iis['home']` resolves to.

Comment: It's probably my ignorance on how to use attributes.  Adding node.default results in FATAL:  NameError:  No resource, method, or local variable named 'iis' for 'Chef::Recipe "iisconfigsettings".  I'd like to be able to use the node['iis']['conf_dir'] attribute in the iis cookbook to set the redirection.config file for shared configuration.  I've used most of the iis resources but I do not know how to utilize attributes here.

Comment: It looks like the proper use for this is:  node.default.iis.conf_dr = "d:\configuration" which tries to utilize appcmd.exe to set the config.  However, after running through how the iis cookbook uses appcmd.exe to set these config changes I don't believe it works for attribute conf_dir.  This setting which actually needs to be modified is in redirection.config and as far as I can tell appcmd.exe won't touch any of the sections in that file.

Comment: The `NameErrro` is from the `"#{iss['home']}` because you don't have anythign called `iis` at this point.  The `node.default...` is correct.